# How to sort out the ranges for a basic trading bot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, stock

I used this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEQbb8w7VTw) to make the stock trading bot. However, I want to edit it so that every time the stock price rises, the bot would buy and every time the stock falls, it would sell (I know it is an awful trading strategy but I just want to try out my python skills). However, I always get the error ValueError: 252 is not in range even when I edit the I value or increase the data length.

```
# Description: This program uses the dual moving average crossover to determine when to buy and sell stock
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt




#Store the data
AAPL = pd.read_csv('AAPL.csv')
#Show the data
print(AAPL)





#Create a new data frame to store all the data
data = pd.DataFrame()
data['AAPL'] = AAPL['Adj Close']



#Create a function to signal when to buy and sell the asset/stock
def buy_sell(data):
    sigPriceBuy = []
    sigPriceSell = []

    for i in range(len(data)):
        #Problem is here
        if data['AAPL'][i+1] > data['AAPL'][i]:
            sigPriceBuy.append(data['AAPL'][i])
            sigPriceSell.append(np.nan)
        elif data['AAPL'][i+1] < data['AAPL'][i]:
            sigPriceBuy.append(np.nan)
            sigPriceSell.append(data['AAPL'][i])
        else:
            sigPriceBuy.append(np.nan)
            sigPriceSell.append(np.nan)
    return (sigPriceBuy, sigPriceSell)
#Store the buy and sell data into a variable
buy_sell = buy_sell(data)
print(buy_sell)
data['Buy_Signal_Price'] = buy_sell[0]
data['Sell_Signal_Price'] = buy_sell[0]
#Visualize tha data and strategy to buy and sell stock
plt.figure(figsize=(12.6, 4.6))
plt.plot(AAPL['Adj Close'], label='AAPL', alpha = 0.35)
plt.scatter(data.index, data['Buy_Signal_Price'], label='Buy', marker='^', color='green')
plt.scatter(data.index, data['Sell_Signal_Price'], label='Sell', marker='v', color='red')
plt.title('Apple Adj. Close Price History')
plt.xlabel('17/6/2021 - 17/6/2021')
plt.ylabel('Adj. Close Price USD ($)')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a good approach but your problem is here as you correctly pointed out:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    if data['AAPL'][i+1] > data['AAPL'][i]:
```

You're attempting to access data at i+1 at the last iteration, that data is not available. Try this instead:

```
for i in range(len(data)-1):
    if data['AAPL'][i+1] > data['AAPL'][i]:
```

As the last index value, you'd need a `np.nan` to match index length:

```
def buy_sell(data):
    sigPriceBuy = []
    sigPriceSell = []

    for i in range(len(data)):
        #Problem is here
        if data['AAPL'][i+1] > data['AAPL'][i]:
            sigPriceBuy.append(data['AAPL'][i])
            sigPriceSell.append(np.nan)
        elif data['AAPL'][i+1] < data['AAPL'][i]:
            sigPriceBuy.append(np.nan)
            sigPriceSell.append(data['AAPL'][i])
        else:
            sigPriceBuy.append(np.nan)
            sigPriceSell.append(np.nan)

    sigPriceBuy.append(np.nan)
    sigPriceSell.append(np.nan)
    return (sigPriceBuy, sigPriceSell)
```

Comment: Ahh right. I just made a type its supposed to be if data['AAPL'][i+1] > data['AAPl'][i]. Sorry about that.

Comment: Not what I was alluding to, notice range has a stop parameter.

Comment: Ahh yeah I realize that. I will try it (But I just mentioned it just in case).

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Range takes no keyword arguments.

Comment: Edited, try it as a simple argument.

Comment: Doesn't work "ValueError: Length of values (251) does not match length of index (252)."

Comment: Edited. Length must match, so you'd add an empty nan at the end.

Answer (score 0):

if you are have looping problem with adjacent values then good python way is to use `zip` function like , i dont't know what is in csv so making simple example you will get idea

```
for curnt_price,next_price in zip(data['AAPL'],data['AAPL'][1:]):
    print(curnt_price,next_price) # so you don't have to IndexError
```

but in your question you are having ValueError so see the index length of DataFrame and length of `buy_sell` return lists. there will always one index short because of we are comparing adjcent values , so you can add `np.nan` for both values as misantroop suggested in his answer or you pass simply `Series` which will add `nan` self like this

```
data['Buy_Signal_Price'] = pd.Series(buy_sell[0])
data['Sell_Signal_Price'] = pd.Sereis(buy_sell[1])
```

*Carefull for both `Buy_Signal_Price` & `Sell_Signal_Price` you are assigning `0` of `buy_sell` which can lead wrong result.

Comment: Yeah, the index value is 252